# Files lost by overwriting into hive managed tables

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am using hadoop 2.7.3 and hive 2.1.1.

I had some 8-9 file in HDFS. I created one internal hive table. I loaded first of those 8 files in that table. Did some operation on that data.

After that I loaded the second of those files by overwriting into that table.

```
load data inpath '/path/path1/first.csv' into table ABC;

load data inpath '/path/path1/second.csv' overwrite into table ABC;
```

Did some operation on second data.

I then loaded third file and so on till the last file by using "overwrite into" .

Now, I see all those files are not there in there original location. Also, at /user/hive/warehouse/ABC only the last of the files is there.

Where did those previous files go? Are they lost because of overwriting into hive table? I did "`hdfs dfs -ls -R / | grep "filename`" but could not find my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INPATH` will move (not copy) the file from the source HDFS path to the table warehouse path.

`OVERWRITE` will delete the files (if HDFS Trash is enabled, move the files to `Trash`) that already exist in the table and replace with the files given in the path.

Answer (score 1):

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH` **copies** the files.
`LOAD DATA INPATH` **moves** the files.
`overwrite` **deletes** existing files before moving in new files.

Comment: Any way I can recover those deleted files?

Comment: Not likely unless you have the HDFS trash enabled and then - 'maybe'.